# Query exchange for sent item count by folder

Tags: exchange, metadata

I have a large Exchange server with many hundreds of thousands of emails in thousands of folders.

I would like to generate a list of how many emails have been sent, by user, for a subset of the public folders.

If I could run SQL against the server (can I?), I would like to run a query along the lines of:

```
SELECT from, count(*)
FROM emails
WHERE email_is_in_folder_or_descendents('Public Folders/Customers/XYZ')
GROUP BY from
```

Is this possible?
I have full administrator access to the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you can query Exchange using the web services.
This link shows how to make a grouped query using the Exchange Web Services Managed API:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exchange/dd633674(v=exchg.80).aspx